# JQM: Correct touch event to use for navigation, that does not fire on finger scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, jquery-mobile, mobile

I am building a cordova application.

I have a page with multiple Navigation buttons on it (16). The nav buttons get wrapped to 2 buttons per line. This causes the page to be scrollable.

I have an issue where when I scroll the page with my finger, the button I am not fires. I don't want any event firing my navigation code when I "scroll" the page.

I have tried `touchstart`, `touchend` and `tap`. From teh docs tap seems to be what I am looking for, and it does seem to handle the scroll better, but the button stays hi-lited. It never fires my navigation code.

Markup:

```
<div data-role="navbar">
       <ul>
                <li><a href="#">
                    <div id="wineButton">
                        <img src="images/images/categories/wine.png" style="width: 45px; height: 45px;" /><br />
                        Wine Tasting
                    </div>
                </a></li>
      </ul>
</div>
```

JS Code

```
        document.getElementById('wineButton').addEventListener('tap', function () {

            currentCategory = "Wine Tasting"
            do_nav();

        }, false);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up writing my own code to check screen tap locations on touch start and touch end, and to determine if it was a tap or a move.